# XSLT gathering data

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have a simple issue that I can't really find a workaround to and I need your help.

The main problem is, that while process an input XML there are various places where I need to "gather" information. This means all I really have to do is call a special template with parameters like so:

```
<xsl:template name="append-section">
        <xsl:param name="id" />
        <xsl:param name="title" />
        <!-- more code here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Lets say this template is called 12 times during the XSLT procedure. At the end of the conversion I want to write this data to a file.

I have tried to appen this data to a global variable and then write the result to the file. Only to realise the variables are not really variables in XSLT. This solution did not work.

Second solution was to use the xsl:result-document with one temp file. This solution would have done something like always copying the previous content of the file to itself, but also appending the new data something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="append-section">
        <xsl:param name="id" />
        <xsl:param name="title" />
        <xsl:result-document method="html" href="tmp/tmp.html">

            <xsl:value-of select="document(tmp.html)" />
            <xsl:element name="li">
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'so-dropdown-page-menu-list-button'" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'#'" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```

This code might not be perfect, but I had to realise unfortunatly that the following exception was thrown:

```
Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI
```

This solution also seems to be invalid.

So my question is this: How can I implement this simple issue? Gather the data from various places and write them to a file at the end of the transformation.

I use Saxon.

Comment: Tell us how the input XML looks and then show us the corresponding HTML you want to construct or collect, then we can suggest an XSLT way of doing so. You might simply want to use a certain mode on templates to collect the information, then use a different mode for other processing if you need different processing steps in one stylesheet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is impossible or at least would be very difficult to accomplish, I'd like if someone could propose a general solution, others may find it helpful, there must be a way to accomplish this.

Comment: If you can show us a specific scenario, perhaps we can propose a generic solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to structure your code according to the structure of the output, not the structure of the input. Don't try to do things as you encounter information in the input; do them when you need to generate the relevant piece of the output.

There are cases when this can seem inefficient because it means visiting the same input more than once. Usually these inefficiences will prove apparent rather than real. But the first thing is to get the transformation working; if it's not fast enough you can come back to us with another question.

Comment: After taking a good night sleep I actually reconsidered the issue and found a somewhat simple solution thanks to your idea. Thanks again Micheal!